# ¿Cómo logro hacer una entidad/relación de usuario puede trabajar varias empresas, pero en cada empresa solo puede existir un usuario * persona?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Amigos tengo la siguiente tabla basada en los lineamientos, lo cual las personas pueden tener varios usuarios en diferentes empresas , pero a su vez en cada empresa solo puede estar un usuario con sus respectivos permisos.

Tengo la siguiente entidad, necesito ayuda a validar si es correcta o alguna relación esta mala.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero saber si estoy modelando bien la base de datos.

Quedo atento a cualquier opinión, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero en tu modelo se entiende que una persona puede tener muchos usuarios? Y en el título colocas que solo puede haber un usuario por persona. Cómo se puede entender ello?

Comment: @lsanchezo, Si, una persona puede tener muchos usuarios para diferentes empresas, pero en una empresa solo puede existir un usuario por persona, no puede tener mas en esa empresa

Comment: Entonces digamos que si una persona tiene múltiples usuarios, cuando se le asigne a la empresa, esa persona solo podrá tener acceso a la empresa con un usuario de los tantos que tiene, correcto?

Comment: @lsanchezo Si señor, exacto

Comment: Listo, entonces la relación está bien, la entidad usuario dependerá de la entidad persona, lo único que estaría mal es la relación de empresa a usuario, debería ser de 1 a 1.

Answer (score 0):

El modelado está bien, simplemente al programar podrías confirmar que no este vinculado con una consulta a la base de datos verificando el id o si la cédula es única también te sirve (dejandola como primarykey y pase a la tabla usuario). Ya que como al usuario le permites más de una cuenta tu lógica está correcta.